# Kill Thread in Pthread Library

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I use `pthread_create(&thread1, &attrs, //... , //...);` and need if some condition occured need to kill this thread how to kill this ?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

First store the thread id

```
pthread_create(&thr, ...)
```

then later call

```
pthread_cancel(thr)
```

However, this not a recommended programming practice! It's better to use an inter-thread communication mechanism like semaphores or messages to communicate to the thread that it should stop execution.

Note that pthread_kill(...) does not actually terminate the receiving thread, but instead delivers a signal to it, and it depends on the signal and signal handlers what happens.

Comment: The problem with pthread_cancel, btw, is that if you use it, then the code running in the thread that's cancelled, has to understand cancellation points, and make sure that (a) it hits one frequently enough that it actually gets cancelled in good time, and (b) it doesn't leak resources when this happens. This is kind of tricky, whereas if you use a message, then it's nicely explicit in your code exactly when the thread can exit.

Comment: @Steve: Unfortunately, `pthread_cancel` is the only clean way *in library code* to interrupt a thread that might be blocked on a syscall. The other method is to install an interrupting signal handler and be sure all of your code is prepared to deal with `EINTR`, but library code cannot assume it has a right to change signal handling or impose `EINTR` handling on the caller.

Answer (score 29):

There are two approaches to this problem.

- Use a **signal**: The thread installs a signal handler using `sigaction()` which sets a flag, and the thread periodically checks the flag to see whether it must terminate. When the thread must terminate, issue the signal to it using `pthread_kill()` and wait for its termination with `pthread_join()`. This approach requires pre-synchronization between the parent thread and the child thread, to guarantee that the child thread has already installed the signal handler before it is able to handle the termination signal;
- Use a **cancellation point**: The thread terminates whenever a cancellation function is executed. When the thread must terminate, execute `pthread_cancel()` and wait for its termination with `pthread_join()`. This approach requires detailed usage of `pthread_cleanup_push()` and `pthread_cleanup_pop()` to avoid resource leakage. These last two calls might mess with the lexical scope of the code (since they may be macros yielding `{` and `}` tokens) and are very difficult to maintain properly.

(Note that if you have already detached the thread using `pthread_detach()`, you cannot join it again using `pthread_join()`.)

Both approaches can be very tricky, but either might be specially useful in a given situation.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with Antti, better practice would be to implement some checkpoint(s) where the thread checks if it should terminate. These checkpoints can be implemented in a number of ways e.g.: a shared variable with lock or an event that the thread checks if it is set (the thread can opt to wait zero time).

Comment: In most general cases this absolutely correct. However, there are many situations in which this is simply not practical. For example, my current project is a minimal text editor, in which I have a dedicated thread for receiving user input. Since `getch()` operates synchronously, my input thread would be unable to detect that it needs to terminate until the user pressed another key. This would be very bad design. Since the user input thread never needs to allocate additional resources, it is far better to kill it with `pthread_cancel()`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `pthread_kill()` function.

Answer (score -2):

```
pthread_exit(0)
```

This will kill the thread.

Comment: This answer is wrong. pthread_exit() is a function used to terminate the thread where this function is called. This is a proper termination. pthread_exit() cannot be used to affect any other thread. Kindly don't mislead.