# How to kill a pthread in ANSI C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a problem with pthreads using <strike>ANSI</strike> C over Linux.

I want to get commands using a thread, so it is waiting for them. But, in a certain case, I need to kill it.

If I use pthread_kill(), it sends a signal and kills the whole process. And, if I am on the right way, pthread_cancel requires the thread to be prepared for it.

Is there any cleaner or more simple way to kill a thread from another one?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084830/kill-thread-in-pthread, use signal handlers and handle pthread_kill()

Comment: Just a side note: You shouldn't say "ANSI C" when you don't mean it. ANSI C is not concerned with threads or other means of executing in parallel. Instead you probably mean a POSIX environment.

Comment: @vpit3833 We thought about that option, may be we should reconsider it... I just wonder if there is more ways.   @Roland Illig: You're right.

Answer (score 4):

You don't say what kind of command/message your thread is waiting for, but if you can send it a "will you please kill yourself" message, and then wait for it to die with pthread_join(...), you'll be much happier.

If your thread is waiting on a file descriptor, you can use poll() or select() and have it wait on two file descriptors.  Then your main thread can send it messages on the second one.

If your thread is waiting on GUI events, most toolkits have a way to send your own messages.  For instance PostMessage() in Win32, or XSendEvent() in X11.

Comment: It's a team work, and I am not coding that, but I think this is only to take commands from stdin (in a program which has to take commands from a file and/or other programs messages). It has not GUI, just CLI. Thanks for the input.

Comment: As a hack then, you could close() stdin, and tell your team mate that this means they need to cleanup and exit.

Comment: Actually, in retrospect I don't even think it is that much of a hack.  :-)

Comment: We're trying that way, but we aren't quite sure about how to do it exactly, how to reopen stdin and how to close it correctly...

Comment: I don't believe you'll be able to reopen stdin because that file handle is created by the calling process.  It sounds like you have more requirements than you listed.