# how to break simple for infinite loop in C by thread

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm looking for solution how to break infinite loop, when the thread will be finished. code is quite complicated, so i show u only the main part. 
Look below

```
 for(;;){     if(stan==false)
              pthread_create(&counter, NULL, count_me, NULL);     
              //to create thread only once in loop

              stan=true;

                  move=getchar();
                  //(...) action.... doesn't matter     
         }
```

As you see, main are waiting for user move in getchar() func. I want to break this loop, after 10 sec from create a thread.

thread def below

```
        void *count_me(void *threadid)
        {
           sleep(10);

           pthread_exit(NULL);

         }
```

thx for your help

Comment: You can't break an infinite loop. If it's breakable, it's not infinite. Anyway, just use a global variable - `volatile int endLoop = 0;`, and set it to 1 from the other thread. Check it each time in the loop.

Comment: I think you actually want to cancel the `getchar`. If I understood correctly, this approach may help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513593/cancelling-getchar

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to add a flag that is set by the thread when it exits, the main thread can then check this flag and call `pthread_join` and break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(;;) 
     {   
          if(breakloop != 0)
          {
          if(stan==false) 
          pthread_create(&counter, NULL, count_me, NULL);     
          //to create thread only once in loop

          stan=true;

              move=getchar();
              //(...) action.... doesn't matter
          }
          else
          { 
              break; 
          } 
     }
```

This should work. Change the breakloop to 1 or something else when you want to break the loop. In your case, create a timer for example.