# pthread exit from thread in thread pool

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a rather simple thread pool, and i have a question regarding thread finalizing.

this is my worker snippet :

```
static void* threadpool_worker(void* pool_instance)
{
    int rc;
    struct threadpool* pool = (struct threadpool*)pool_instance;
    struct threadpool_task *task;

    for(;;)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock( &(pool->task_queue_mutex) );

        while( pool->headp->tqh_first == NULL )
        {
            rc = pthread_cond_wait( &(pool->task_queue_cond), &(pool->task_queue_mutex) );
        }

        task = pool->headp->tqh_first;
        TAILQ_REMOVE(pool->headp, pool->headp->tqh_first, entries);

       pthread_mutex_unlock( &(pool->task_queue_mutex) );
       task->routine_cb(task->data);
    }

}
```

so jobs are executed at this line task->routine_cb(task->data);

and in order to finalize workers threads i'm calling threadpool_enqueue_task

in the following way :

```
for( i=0 ; i < pool->num_of_workers ; ++i)
{
    threadpool_enqueue_task(pool, pthread_exit, NULL);
}
```

expecting that pthread_exit will be called in here task->routine_cb(task->data)
but it does not work this way, i don't see any explicit error, just memory leak in valgrind

but when i change the worker code like that :

```
    if(task->routine_cb == pthread_exit)
    {
        pthread_exit(0);
    }
    task->routine_cb(task->data);
```

everything ends fine. 
so my question is is there an option to stop the worker just making it to execute pthread_exit in some way,without changing the worker code.

Edit:
    Thread pool task declared as following :

```
struct threadpool_task
{
    void (*routine_cb)(void*);
    void *data;
    TAILQ_ENTRY(threadpool_task) entries;          /* List. */
}
```

As per my understanig there should be no problem to get address of pthread_exit in routine_cb which declared :

```
extern void pthread_exit (void *__retval) __attribute__ ((__noreturn__));
```

Comment: Is this helpful ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084830/kill-thread-in-pthread-library

Comment: they suggest actually something that i'm trying to avoid, id on't want to use pthread_cancel from the reasons mentioned in that post:
pthread_cancel(thr)
However, this not a recommended programming practice! It's better to use an inter-thread communication mechanism like semaphores or messages to communicate to the thread that it should stop execution.

Comment: What OS/compiler do you use?

Comment: How is `routine_cb` declared?

Comment: "*... but it does not work this way ...*", so the threads do **not** end? They are still around? Did you try enqueing a wrapper to `pthread_exit()` logging it was called?

Comment: My OS is ubuntu 13.04, g++ compiler.
this is my threadpool_task declaration

struct threadpool_task
{
 void (*routine_cb)(void*);
 void *data;
 TAILQ_ENTRY(threadpool_task) entries;          /* List. */
}

Comment: pthread_exit called and threads appears to be dead, but i see that memory leak, which makes me think that it fails somewhere

Comment: Too many unknowns. Can you reproduce this behaviour in a small self-contained example?

Comment: Just to add - in general there's nothing wrong with using `pthread_cancel()`, as long as you make sure that your code is written with cancellation in mind - that is, make sure that cancellation points exist, and that you create cleanup handlers when necessary.

Comment: did you investigate what memory leak valgrind reported?

Comment: @n.m. I don't really see how it's possible to shrink this example without knowing where the problem is.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to shrink the example (though it would be nice). You do  need to make it self-contained, so that the behaviour could be verified.

Comment: Without seeing what valgrind said it's a little difficult to help. There's nothing there, at the time of this writing, that could leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the leak. It was my fault of course. I rewrote the job invocation in the following way :

```
    void (*routine)(void*) = task->routine_cb;
    void* data = task->data;
    free(task);
    routine(data);
```

instead of :

```
    task->routine_cb(task->data);
    free(task);
```

and there were no more leaks, and threads stopped as i expected.
Thanks to everyone who tried to help.