# terminate all threads or currently running thread keeping the process alive in c++

Tags: c++, linux, terminate, terminate-handler

I want to kill all currently running threads of a process when it receives a stop message. But I want the process to still keep running to accept new requests. I using c++ std::thread and not pthreads

Comment: Forward the stop message to all running threads and have them check for the message periodically and return if found.

Comment: The process has 1 more thread than the n threads it launched.  I call this thread 'main()', and it continues to run until it exits.

Comment: You probably don't want to kill (terminate) the threads because they might be holding a lock or something else that will bugger up everything.  You want to ask them nicely to terminate when they are at a good point.  That means the threads need to check periodically if they should exit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kill Thread in Pthread Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084830/kill-thread-in-pthread-library)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But I don't use pthread library

Comment: Yep added a stop flag and checked periodically. Works fine but is there a similar way to pause a thread and later make it proceed from where it stopped. I know sleeping until a condition is met is one solution

Answer (score 2):

In short: You can't kill threads in ISO c++. You can only e.g. repeatedly poll a flag inside the thread and stop further processing.

As std::threads are usually implemented on top of pthreads on linux, you might be able to leverage that API, e.g. have a look at [pthread_cancel](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html). Keep in mind however, that  this won't trigger any c++ destructors, so you have to be very careful when you do this to avoid resource leaks.